# Java transferTo(out) is replying after each character instead of after pressing Enter

Tags: java, sockets

I've just moved and my application is acting differently that it used to and indeed differently than makes any sense to me.

**EXPECTED:**
(Microsoft Telnet) -> telnet localhost 8010

Keyboard Input1:
hello

Console Output1:
hello

Keyboard Input2:
this

Console Output2:
this

**ACTUAL:**
telnet localhost 8010

Keyboard Input1:
a

Console Output1:
a

Keyboard Input2:
4

Console Output2:
44

and so on... it just immediately repeats each character.

```
public class SingleThreadedBlockingServerBasic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(8010);


        while (true) {

            // Connect client and serverSock - Tell serverSock to accept client Socket
            Socket client = serverSock.accept();

            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

            int data;

            // Read the int-read into the 8k buffer at offset 0 from the inputstream. inputstream receives data off
            // of the client Socket.
            in.transferTo(out);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your client?

Comment: @IlyaGazman Hmm Im using the same client as I had before.. MS Telnet application available with WIndows

Comment: It's sounds like it is working the way it is supposed to, sending each character as soon as it is typed.

Comment: Where exactly does it say that `transferTo()` should wait for newlines?

Comment: Ok I'll write up an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Telnet session responds to the user's input one character at a time, it does not wait for a carriage return before sending the user's input as MacOS and some Linux telnet do.

Thank you user207421, james-k-polk for your information.